# What is the complexity of (prime?) factorization with a fixed number of primes?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity, number-theory

I was wondering what the complexity of factorization (on quantum computers or classical computers) is if we know that there must be exactly two prime numbers and we know the two prime numbers.

For instance, if we know that our two prime numbers are $2$ and $3$ we want to know what $a$ and $b$ are because our number $N=2^a\cdot 3^b$ ($a,b>0$).

I am sorry if the title might be misleading.

I am thankful for any answers :)

Comment: This is not the usual meaning of factorization. Are you trying to solve the following problem? Given integers $n,a,b$, find $x,y$ such that $n=ax+by$, or determine that no such representation exists.

Comment: You can look factorization up on Wikipedia.

Comment: I made another typo .. Now it should we be right.

Comment: Keep dividing by 2 until reaching an odd number, then by 3 until reaching 1.

Comment: This approach that @YuvalFilmus gives works in time $O(a+b)=O(\log(N))$. I don't think there is a significantly faster way to do this :)

Comment: Thank you guys very much.